# Switching the order of summations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Why is the below statement true?

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(-\sum_{t=0}^{k}{{k+1}\choose {t}}j^t(-1)^{k+1-t}\right) = -\sum_{t=0}^{k}{{k+1}\choose {t}}(-1)^{k+1-t}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}j^t\right)$$

More generally, under what conditions are we allowed to bring the outer summation inside, and if possible maybe a simple example to provide an intuitive understanding of **why** it works under those conditions (if any).

I know that when a term in the inner summation doesn't depend on the index of the inner summation, we can bring since it is like a constant, but this is not the case since $j^t$ depends on both $t$ and $j$. The only other questions I have found related to this topic were regarding infinite sums, so help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it's just because the term in the sum consists of terms that are all independent of $j$ (except $j^t$)

Comment: You can always swap finite sumations, so long as the indexes of the inner sum don't depend on the indexes of the outer sum. Basically, imagine a big grid that's n+1 by k+1, and we index each box in the natural way, and insert the summand corresponding to the index pair into the box. Does it matter if we total the rows first and then total the totals, or whether wwe total the columns first and then total the totals? No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both expressions simply give you the sum of all terms of the form

$$-\binom{k+1}t j^t(-1)^{k+2-t}$$

for pairs $\langle j,t\rangle$ such that $j\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$ and $t\in\{0,\ldots,k\}$. You can think of these numbers as being arranged in an $(n+1)\times(k+1)$ matrix with rows indexed by $j$ and columns by $t$. Ignoring the minus sign, the first expression calculates the sum of each row and then adds up these row sums; the second calculates the column sums and then adds them up. Clearly the totals will be the same.

What makes this work is that the limits of the inner summation are constant: they don't depend on the outer index variable. You have essentially the same thing in calculus when you change the order of integration over a rectangular region:

$$\int_a^b\int_c^df(x,y)\,dxdy=\int_c^d\int_a^bf(x,y)\,dydx\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify your question first. What you have is:

$$\sum_{j=0}^n \left(-\sum_{t=0}^k f(k,t) g(j,t)\right)$$
for some function $f$ (in your particular case: $f(k,t) = {k+1\choose t}(-1)^{k+1-t}$ and $g$ (in your case, $g(j, t)  = j^t$.

Let's forget what $g$ and $g$ are for the moment because it's not relevant.

The sum $$S=\sum_{j=0}^n \left(-\sum_{t=0}^k f(k,t) g(j,t)\right)$$
can be first rewritten as

$$S=-\sum_{j=0}^n \left(\sum_{t=0}^k f(k,t) g(j,t)\right)$$

Now, let's reverse the order of summing. In the original case, you sum something from $j=0$ to $j=n$, and for every $j$, you sum the inner sum from $t=0$ to $t=k$, which means you cover the whole square $\{(j,t)\in\mathbb Z^2| 0\leq j\leq n\land 0\leq t\leq k\}$.

You can cover the same square by summing first over $t$ and then over $j$, so you get

$$S=-\sum_{t=0}^k \left(\sum_{j=0}^n f(k,t) g(j,t)\right)$$

Now, for every value of $t$, you can see that

$$\sum_{j=0}^n f(k, t)g(j,t) = f(k,t)\sum_{j=0}^n g(j,t)$$

because you are just factoring out the common factor $f(k,t)$. It becomes ogvious if you write it as

$$\sum_{j=0}^n f(k, t)g(j,t) = f(k,t) g(0,t) + f(k,t)g(1,t) + \dots + f(k,t)g(n,t) = f(k,t) (g(0,t) + g(1,t) + \dots + g(n,t)) = f(k,t)\sum_{j=0}^n g(j,t)$$

So now you get

$$S=-\sum_{t=0}^k \left(f(k,t)\sum_{j=0}^n g(j,t)\right)$$

which is what you wanted to have in the first place.